# Javascript, Ramda, Typescript- Rename key to an correct case

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ramda.js

I have an object with keys in camelCase

```
{
  "studentName": "ABC",
  "studentId": "12345",
  "age": 18,
  "submittedAt": "xxxxxx"
}
```

I want to convert object above into keys snake_case

```
{
  "student_name": "ABC",
  "student_id": "12345",
  "age": 18,
  "submitted_at": "xxxxxx"
}
```

I have a function to convert from camelCase to snakeCase

```
const camelToSnakeCase = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);
```

However, I am quite confused about how to convert keys inside JSON object. Any suggetion is appreciated.

Comment: (of course apply your own transformation in place of `toLowerCase()` in the proposed duplicate)

Comment: If you're interested in an approach to handle nested properties too, I have a [vanilla JS version](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/64) and [a Ramda one](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/65).

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertObjectKeys(object) {
  const newObject = new Object
  const keys = Object.keys(object)

  keys.forEach((k) => {
    newObject[camelToSnakeCase(k)] = object[k] 
  })

  return newObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach.

```js
const camelToSnakeCase = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);

const myObj = {
  "studentName": "ABC",
  "studentId": "12345",
  "age": 18,
  "submittedAt": "xxxxxx"
}


Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
  const newKey = camelToSnakeCase(key);

  if(newKey !== key) {
    myObj[newKey] = myObj[key];
    delete myObj[key];
  }
    
})


console.log(myObj)
```